# Auto-hide 2nd level drop-down on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with a drop-down menu that does not hide when I mouseout from the 2nd level dropdown trigger. Here's the sample code from my [webpage](http://www.mediafire.com/?ckbqgx4lsgv6no9) pass:dropotron.

On my webpage I use a dropdown javascript called "dropdown" to make it work.

Here's the html dropdown-featured menu codes:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="opener">1st Level<b></b></span><ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li>
        <span>2nd Level<b></b></span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">This level does not</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">auto hide when</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">mouseout from 2nd level</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the css that is connected to the dropdown menu:

```
#menu {
    padding: 0 45px 0 45px;
    position: relative;
    background: #209D9D url(images/img02.png) repeat-x top left;
    margin: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 890px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #007D7D;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 12px;
    left: -42px;
    width: 110%;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu ul li a, #menu ul li span {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

#menu ul li span b {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 7px solid #00eaff;
    margin-left: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

#menu ul li.active {
    background: #009bec;
    border-top: solid 1px #007cbc;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

#menu ul li.active span b {
    border-top-color: #37cdff;
}

.dropotron {
    background: rgba(0,155,236,0.9);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #1d7bc1;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #007D7D;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dropotron a, .dropotron span {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.dropotron span b {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 7px solid #00eaff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 7px;
}

.dropotron li:hover span b {
    border-left-color: #37cdff;
}

.dropotron li {
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
    margin: 7px 0 7px 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.dropotron li:hover, .dropotron li.active {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background: rgba(35,125,205,0.9);
    border-top: solid 1px #1e6db2;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #2c9cff;
}

.dropotron-level-1 {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please share some code, links to existing projects are not sufficient for getting help.

Comment: ok sorry, my bad. it was my first time to ask around here.

I re-edited my question, please take your time to view.

Comment: FYI you can achieve what you're after with just CSS.

Comment: if you trying to achieve it with javascript/jQuery, then you should post your javascript function that controlls your menu, so we can take a look at it. Also, make sure your CSS has same id's and classes that your HTML. In the fragment you submitted there is no link between HTML and CSS styles.

Comment: first I'd like to apologize for a very late reply, because I was so busy this month.

yes, there is something I'd like to do with it's dropdown menu javascript. So far, I still haven't find a real solution on how to auto-hide it with within the CSS. I think there is something wrong with it's dropdown menu javascript..

remember that the dropdown menu javascript was from JQuery called "dropotron".

Comment: and right now, I just found a simple temporary solution that can auto-hide. finally! now I need to apply a simple fading transition when displaying and hiding. And thank you everyone for your help, I appreciated it.